# High noise in background while playing audio in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound

I have just shifted to Ubuntu from Windows OS. I am a noob in Linux. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my desktop computer as stand alone OS. 
But whenever playing any audio, I hear high pitch background noise with the original audio. Can you please help me to sole this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try installing reinstalling latest audio driver for your system, and if that does not work , try installing gnome alsa mixer through terminal with the following command
sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer

Comment: I couldn't find any linux driver in my motherboard manufacturer's website. I have a Gigabyte GA-H61M -DS2 model.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved. I just went to the Sound app and set the Output to 'Line Out' instead of 'Headphones'. Thanks for your help.