# Multitouch and Headphone White Noise on Asus Zenbook Pro UX501VM with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, touchpad, multi-touch

I have installed Ubuntu on my Asus Zenbook Pro UX501VM and I have two problems : I've partly fixed the headphone noise and I have no clue for the touchpad 
   I can't use 2 finger scolling and other mutitouch tasks.

I have fixed the headphone noise temporary by changing a confing in **/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf** i have added this line :

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

But when I close my laptop and reopen it the noise comes back. Even if I restart ALSA and pulseaudio.

My kernel version is **4.6.0-040600-generic** (i have tried 4.3.5 but the computer won't boot anymore).

I have nvidia drivers.

Comment: +1 I have the Same Issue.. and
[ wrote a question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/827685/high-noise-in-background-while-playing-audio-in-ubuntu-16-04/851455#851455)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: Do you know where the static is coming from?  If you have pulseaudio volume control look for where that could be coming from.